# kafka + This server is not the leader for that topic-partition + kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, hdp

We are get many errors from `server.log` from each of `3` kafka machines ( we have `3` kafka in the cluster )

```
[2019-12-05 13:25:09,529] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error for partition [jdty.dee.rules.time,91] to broker 1001:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2019-12-05 13:25:09,529] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error for partition [jdty.dee.export.profiles,96] to broker 1001:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2019-12-05 13:25:09,529] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error for partition [jdty.dee.control.tt.state,40] to broker 1001:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2019-12-05 13:25:09,529] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error for partition [jdty.dee.control.tt,67] to broker 1001:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

from my understanding each topic is served by one or multiple Brokers - one is leader and the remaining brokers are followers.

A producer needs to send new messages to the leader Broker which internally replicate the data to all followers.

I assume, that your producer client does not connect to the correct Broker, its connect to a follower instead of the leader, and this follower rejects your send request.

so my question is - how to configure the producer configuration in order to avoid such these errors?

Comment: Normally connecting to the leader is handled automatically.  Is your broker healthy?  Are there any problems with replication for the topic you listed?

Comment: I think my kafka cluster is ok and I not see problem with replication , but I need more steps of verification to test all you wrote

Comment: if it possible p-lease post your suggestion

Comment: Use `kafka-topics.sh` to describe your topics.

Comment: I already did it , and all brokers are balanced - if is is your question

Comment: it will be better if you post all checks that I need to perform on my kafka cluster , so I will check again all your comments , but as I said in my question I think this problem is about producer configuration ( I searched in google and this is what I found ) , but please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: let me know if you need some additional logs , from kafka cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follower brokers fetch from the leader broker (the leader is not pushing to followers). Hence, it seems that a follower broker tries to fetch from the wrong (leader) broker. This can happen if the leader of a partition changed. The corresponding follower broker should update its cluster metadata automatically to rediscover the new leader. If the error persists, it indicates that this follower broker has issues to update its metadata.

Comment: since the metadata on zookeepers server . do you mean we need to check the zookeeper ? , until now we not saw problem on zookeeper servers , please advice more details how to check the metadata on zoo servers?

Comment: so can you please give me some direction , we are got lost here